# VScode gives this warning in python, the line works well, but the warning stays there

Tags: python

```
    os.mkdir("Library/Preset")
    WriteFile(r"Library/Preset/characters.txt", r"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzåäöABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÅÄÖ1234567890" + "<>^~¨'*+´,.-;:_?!\"#¤%&/()=?@£$€{[]}\§½| \n")
```

The second line gives warning at "characters.txt":

Anomalous backslash in string: '\§'. String constant might be missing an r prefix.

At first vscode gave the error on the long set of characters string, when it was one whole string, until I cut it apart, into two pieces. The warning decided to move to the characters.txt part. The original code was the long sets of strings, but in one 'normal' string, without a prefix. The warning was at that point between abcdef...890. This warning does not make sense, it forces it to that line of code, no matter what I do. I use the python extension by Microsoft.

The WriteFile(path, text) function, just opens a file with the first parameter (path, string) and writes the second parameter (string) into the file and closes it

Comment: You either need to make the second piece of that string a raw string as well, or double the backslash to escape it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like python thinks that you are trying to espace that character. Just do `\\` to escape the backslash:

```
    os.mkdir("Library/Preset")
    WriteFile(r"Library/Preset/characters.txt", r"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzåäöABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÅÄÖ1234567890" + "<>^~¨'*+´,.-;:_?!\"#¤%&/()=?@£$€{[]}\\§½| \n")
```

The `\` character is used in escape sequences like the newline character for example: `\n`

Comment: Yes, it worked. It was such an obvious mistake, which I didn't notice. Thank you

Comment: @MrRodvor No problem. I am glad that I could help you.